# In the Harry Potter universe, can memories stored in vials only be used once?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In the Harry Potter films, characters seem to pour the contents of memory vials out completely (at least as far as I can tell).  Does that mean that memories can only be used once?

Comment: I imagine the memories can be removed from the pensieve the same way they were removed from the, uh, donor's head: via a spell.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the books, the memories can be put back into a vial after use. That memories are reusable should be clear from the fact that Dumbledore shows Harry memories he himself has seen before individually.